# Convert SQL WHERE IN to JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database storing various information about fictional people. There is a table person with general information, such as name, adress etc and some more specific tables holding health history and education for everyone.
What I'm trying to do now, is getting possible connections for one person based on similarities like being at the same school for the same time or having the same doctor or being treated in the same hospital at the same time.

Following Query works fine for this (:id being the id of the person in question), however it is horribly slow (takes about 6secs to get a result).

```
SELECT person.p_id as id, fname, lname, image FROM person WHERE 
                (person.p_id IN (
                    SELECT patient from health_case WHERE 
                        doctor IN (SELECT doctor FROM health_case WHERE patient =:id ) 
                        OR center IN (SELECT hc2.center FROM health_case as hc1, health_case as hc2 WHERE hc1.patient = :id AND hc2.center = hc1.center AND (hc1.start <= hc2.end AND hc1.end >= hc2.start)))
                OR person.p_id IN (
                    SELECT ed2.pupil FROM education as ed1, education as ed2 WHERE 
                        ed1.school IN (SELECT school FROM education WHERE pupil = :id) AND ed2.school = ed1.school AND (ed2.start <= ed1.end AND ed2.end >= ed1.start)
                )) 
                AND person.p_id != :id
```

What would be the best approach to convert it to use JOIN clauses? I somehow seem unable to wrap my head around these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. There is more than one way to skin a cat, but may I suggest splitting your query into two separate queries, and then replacing the complicated WHERE clause with a couple inner joins? So, something like this:

```
/* Find connections based on health care */
SELECT p2.p_id as id, p2.fname, p2.lname, p2.image
FROM person p
JOIN health_case hc on hc.patient = p.p_id
JOIN health_case hc2 on hc2.doctor = hc.doctor and hc2.healthcenter = hc.healthcenter and hc.start <= hc2.end and hc.end >= hc2.start and hc2.patient <> hc.patient
JOIN person p2 on p2.p_id = hc2.patient and p2.p_id <> p.p_id
WHERE p.p_id = :id
```

Then, create a separate query to get connections based on education:

```
/* Find connections based on education */
SELECT p2.p_id as id, p2.fname, p2.lname, p2.image
FROM person p
JOIN education e on e.pupil = p.p_id
JOIN education e2 on e2.school = e.school and e2.start <= e.end AND e2.end >= e.start and e.pupil <> e2.pupil
JOIN person p2 on p2.p_id = e2.pupil and p2.p_id <> p.p_id
WHERE p.p_id = :id
```

If you really want the data results to be combined, you can use `UNION` since both queries return the same columns from the person table.

Comment: This should work, and rather nicely too, but be careful, you're about to hit the limit of what most would recommend with the number of joins to use before considering restructuring your schema a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your tip on the schema structure, @Z!

Comment: After testing around a bit, I think this works and is really fast too. Splitting the queries is propably a good idea anyway to categorize possible connections.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your SQL engine.  Newer SQL systems that have reasonable query optimizers will most likely rewrite both IN and JOIN queries to the same plan.  Typically, a sub-query (IN Clause) is rewritten using a join.

In simple SQL engines that may not have great query optimizers, the join should be faster because they may run sub-queries into a temporary in-memory table before running the outer query.

In some SQL engines that have limited memory footprint, however, the sub-query may be faster because it doesn't require joining -- which produces more data.