# passing a value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm not sure I picked the correct title, but I did my best to explain what I am trying to do. I am just learning about joins and I have two tables that I am trying to combine in a certain way, but they both have WHERE clauses.

I started out by building both SELECT statements separately. Here is my first one from the table: "shipping_zones"

```
SELECT MIN(cal_zone) AS output_zone
  FROM (
    SELECT carrier, dest_zip, origin_zip, zone, MIN(zone) OVER(PARTITION BY carrier) as cal_zone
      FROM shipping_zones z
        WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = 015
      ) as t
WHERE zone=cal_zone;
```

This returns:

```
+-------------+
| output_zone |
+-------------+
| 5           |
+-------------+
```

My second table is: "shipping_prices" and my query is:

```
SELECT carrier, speed, zone, min_price
FROM (SELECT carrier, zone, speed, price, MIN(price) OVER(PARTITION BY speed) as min_price
      FROM shipping_prices
      WHERE total_wt = 66 and zone = 6
     ) t
WHERE price=min_price
ORDER BY speed DESC;
```

and the result is:

```
+---------+-------+------+-----------+
| carrier | speed | zone | min_price |
+---------+-------+------+-----------+
| fedex   | slow  | 6    | 45.66     |
| usps    | med   | 6    | 96.05     |
| usps    | fast  | 6    | 347.15    |
+---------+-------+------+-----------+
```

What I want to do is "pass" the value for *output_zone* from the first query as an "argument" into the 2nd query. I put argument word in quotes because I'm not sure that is the correct word.

I the best to accomplish this in SQL is to use a join correct? I understand the basic syntax of a join but am a bit lost because of clauses I'm using in both (WHERE, MIN, ORDER BY, etc.)

EDIT: This data is bring queried with Impala and was created in MySQL before being imported into HDFS with HIVE.

EDIT2: I should also mention that the "shipping_prices" table already has a field in it called "zone". So I guess I wouldn't be "passing" it so much as using its value from the output of the first query to find the appropriate tuples in the "shipping_prices" table.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You should add the RDBMS that you are using, preferably as a tag. Some solutions work only for MySql, or SQL Server, or Oracle...

Comment: Mysql already supported `window functions` in GA release? or is it Mysql 8.0 which is one development release?

Comment: Yes but can't this be accomplished more easily with joins? Why would you recommend window functions?

Comment: In second query, what about replacing `zone=6` with `zone in (first_query)`?

Comment: Oh didn't know you could do something like that. do you know the syntax or have link to a help page?

Comment: Nevermind I found some information here: (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp). I think I got it working. Don't think it is the most elegant. If you type up an answer I'll accept it. I basically just copied the first query and put it inside of an IN() operators as you suggested. It seems to be working.

Comment: check this url: [convert in to join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076750/convert-sql-where-in-to-join)

Comment: also you should exec [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html), then optimize your query to more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can put your first query into one `zone in (first_query)` statement to replace `zone=6`.

**The codes will be like below:**

```
SELECT carrier, speed, zone, min_price
FROM (SELECT carrier, zone, speed, price, MIN(price) OVER(PARTITION BY speed) as min_price
      FROM shipping_prices
      WHERE total_wt = 66 
      and zone in (
        SELECT MIN(cal_zone) AS output_zone
          FROM (
            SELECT carrier, dest_zip, origin_zip, zone, MIN(zone) OVER(PARTITION BY carrier) as cal_zone
              FROM shipping_zones z
                WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = 015
              ) as t
        WHERE zone=cal_zone;
      )
     ) t
WHERE price=min_price
ORDER BY speed DESC;
```

It seems you are using Mysql 8.0 (Development Release), The Mysql Engine will  do reasonable query optimization which will most likely rewrite both **IN** and **JOIN** queries to the same plan. Check this URL for the details [Convert IN to JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076750/convert-sql-where-in-to-join)